# Stored procedure with limited number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to build a stored procedure where I am able to extract data in bit size piece.

For example, if I have 1000 rows of data, I need to get it in batches of maybe first 10 or 100 and in the next run the next 10 or 100.

`SELECT TOP 100` will only keep giving the first 100 rows but will ignore anything else.

Thanks,
Vicky

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have `TOP 100`, that's SQL-Server syntax. MySQL uses `LIMIT #rows, starting_row`. You can use the second number for pagination. `LIMIT 100, 0` then `LIMIT 100, 100`, then `LIMIT 100, 200` and so on.

Comment: Thanks I guess it is pagination, do you have any examples in that I can use in stored procedure. Its basically a list of employees that I would like to break in pages and extract from the SP one page at a time.

Comment: No I don't have any samples. Since the LIMT parameters have to be constants, not variables, you'll have to create dynamic SQL using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`. You can make the page number a parameter to the procedure, then calculate `page_num * 100` to get the starting row.